# OpenOCD Failed to execute MI command: -target-select remote localhost:3333

Tags: arm, cortex-m, openocd, swd

I'm used to using Segger at work, but I didn't want to spend that kind of money for home use, so this is my first time using OpenOCD for debugging.
I've got the Olimex ARM-USB-TINY-H.

My OS is Ubuntu.
I'm using MCUXpresso (Eclipse) with the OpenOCD Plugin.
I'm having problems with gdb connecting to OpenOCD.
Any pointers would be super helpful.

I've got the config options set to

```
-s /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/  -f /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts/interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg -f /home/username/Documents/Code/kl27z-ARM_USB_TINY.cfg
```

The console output:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : FTDI SWD mode enabled
none separate
Info : add flash_bank kinetis kl27.flash
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
none separate
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Started by GNU MCU Eclipse
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

Eclipse Pops up this error:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333
Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Connection timed out.
Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333
Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Connection timed out.
localhost:3333: Connection
```

Here is the .cfg file

```
# inteface: olimex arm usb tiny h
# transport: swd

# adapter/interface
#interface ftdi
#source [find interface/ftdi/olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h.cfg]

transport select swd

# increase working area to 16KB
# set WORKAREASIZE 0x4000

set CHIPNAME kl27

#reset_config srst_only srst_nogate connect_assert_srst
reset_config none separate

source [find target/klx.cfg]

ftdi_layout_signal SWD_EN -data 0

$CHIPNAME.cpu configure -event examine-end {
    kinetis mdm check_security
}

#gdb_memory_map disable

$_TARGETNAME configure -event gdb-attach {
   echo "Halting Target"
   reset init
}
```

Update, running with --debug 0 the last part of the console is

```
Debug: 272 20 transport.c:239 handle_transport_init(): handle_transport_init
Debug: 273 20 ftdi.c:1223 ftdi_swd_switch_seq(): JTAG-to-SWD
Debug: 274 20 ftdi.c:1077 ftdi_swd_run_queue(): Executing 2 queued transactions
Debug: 275 20 ftdi.c:1109 ftdi_swd_run_queue(): JUNK DP read reg 0 = 00000000
Debug: 276 20 command.c:626 run_command(): Command failed with error code -4
User : 277 21 command.c:687 command_run_line(): in procedure 'init' 
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
Debug: 278 21 command.c:626 run_command(): Command failed with error code -4
User : 279 21 command.c:687 command_run_line():
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was mostly the ftdi driver, but also a little bit of config. I outlined what I did on my blog.
https://mitchjonesengineering.us/?p=18

Comment: Page not found!